# How do I do M. Bison's super and ultra moves?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv

First off, what I'm trying to do is the moves where the camera changes and it's super powerful like all the computer characters do to me all the time, especially Zangief that piece of poop.

I watched this tutorial:

I read this page: http://www.eventhubs.com/moves/sf4/mbison/

But what do those pics even mean? I've been trying for a while to do it, and I can't. I am in tutorial mode, with the button inputs showing on the screen, with super and ultra all the way up.

For the joystick part, I can't get the button input to show that I'm pushing both directions at the same time. And when I do them in order, it still doesn't work.

For the kick 3x part, I've tried using the left trigger because it does all three at the same time, and I've tried tapping each one 3x. Neither way works.

Comment: I'm willing to read every tutorial, watch hours of youtube, and spend days in my living room playing xbox, whatever it takes to beat that piece of poop Zangief and that other poop man Seth. And Dhalsim that firebreathing poop man. Go Bison! Lightning skull wings society 4ever!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For M. Bison's ultras, you need to hold the joystick backwards (away from the opponent) for a while, then very quickly move it to forward, then backward, then forward, and finally press all of the three punch or kick buttons simultaneously. Which buttons to press depends on which ultra you have selected. Alternatively you can press one of the buttons assigned to PPP or KKK. It takes a bit of practice, but shouldn't be too hard once you get the hang of it.

Before attempting the ultra, make sure that you are able to do his Psycho Crusher and Scissor Kicks special moves first; hold back for a bit, then move the joystick forward and quickly press a button. The super and ultras essentially just add a forward-back fling of the joystick inbetween.

If you don't want to move while holding the joystick backwards, you can hold back-down diagonally, so that your character is crouching. After charging for an appropriate amount of time, quickly execute the rest of the motion.